# Python logging - overview of currently installed loggers/handlers

Tags: python, django, logging, fluentd

I am trying to set up a Fluentd log handler from a Django project using a logger from code:

```
def get_fluentd_logger(name):
    import logging
    from fluent import handler

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.addHandler(handler.FluentHandler(name, host='localhost', port=24224))
    return logger
```

`handler.FluentHandler` comes from package `fluent-logger` and I am running `fluent` locally.

fluent.conf:

```
<source>
  type forward
  port 24224
</source>

<match **>
  type copy
  <store>
        type stdout
  </store>

  <store>
          type forward
          send_timeout 60s
          recover_wait 10s
          heartbeat_interval 1s
          phi_threshold 8
          hard_timeout 60s

          <server>
            name monitoring
            host 1.2.3.4
            port 24224
            weight 100
          </server>
  </store>
</match>
```

When I run this from a non-django python project it works fine, but when called from django it just does not do anything.

The question is: is there a way to see the currently installed loggers and their handlers so I can debug this situation?

[EDIT]

When done from the django settings like this:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
       'fluentdebug':{
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'fluent.handler.FluentHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'tag':'foo.bar.baz',
            'host':'localhost',
            'port':24224,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'foo.bar.baz': {
            'handlers': ['fluentdebug'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

It does work. I however would like to be able to do this from code because `foo.bar.baz` can take many values and I dont want to pollute this file with 20 loggers and handlers that do exactly the same.

Maybe the real question is: Why cant I add loggers from code to `logging` after Django has performed it's setup?

Comment: offtopic: It is funny to see how activity around questions takes off after America is finally awake. Two hours to go from now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to answer myself because if somebody runs in the same problem it is easier to find.
The problem seems to be with the `FluentHandler`. Using Brandon's Logging tree as mentioned by @Thomas we could see that the loggers were correctly added.

However further debugging showed that if you not explicitly set the loglevel it is set to `NotSet`. Somehow in "ordinary" python this is ok and the record is emitted. In Django however `NotSet` level logs are thrown away. I don't know if this is standard Django behaviour, but it caused a lot of headaces. Below is the code that worked:

```
def get_fluentd_logger(name):
    import logging
    from fluent import handler

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.level = logging.INFO
    handler = handler.FluentHandler(name, host='localhost', port=24224)
    handler.level = logging.INFO
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger
```

Comment: Not mine, it's [Brandon Rhodes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/85360/brandon-rhodes)'

Answer (score 4):

This isn't something I've dealt with before, but [Logging Tree](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/logging_tree) sounds like what you might be looking for. You ought to read [Brandon's post](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2012/logging_tree/) about it, but here's an example of output:

```
<--""
   Level WARNING
   Handler Stream <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at ...>
   |
   o<--[cherrypy]
       |
       o<--"cherrypy.access"
       |   Level INFO
       |   Handler Stream <open file '<stdout>', mode 'w' ...>
       |
       o<--"cherrypy.error"
           Level INFO
           Handler Stream <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' ...>
```

Comment: This looks interesting. Ill give it a go.

Comment: Python is a dynamic language, you can read the can and dig in the innards of the logging module yourself. Especially since this looks like a debugging issue and there's not particular concern with working on all versions of python.